# Create document (pdf, html, jpeg..) from form in jsp page and upload it in GAE-JAVA blobstoreService

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

My problem is the following: 
I need to create a document from a classic data entry form and save this in google blobstore. My initial strategy was to create a pdf document through `iText` or similar, but I found constraints using `GAE`. I then thought about converting `jsp` content to `base64` with `Html2Canvas` and sending, through ajax, the content to the servlet /upload file handling. This Servlet already used for classic file upload.
Also this strategy was not optimal as I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

Some other alternative?

Ajax solution:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

console.log(dataURL);
    $.ajax({
        url: "<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>",
        data: "myFile=" + dataURL,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    ...
...
```

Comment: Why don't you create a JSON and convert it to Blob? Are you going to reuse retrieve and reuse them? WRT to Java heap space, take a look at JVM parameters and update them, according to your needs.

Comment: I doesn t understand why my solution is wrong! How can i do it? How from canvas type i create json? and then create blob? thanks